# Why is the SQL transaction not being rolled back?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions

Here is the script with the unnecessary parts striped out

```
USE databaseName

BEGIN TRY 
    DECLARE @count INT 
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg VARCHAR(MAX) 

    SET @count=(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM   xxxtable 
                WHERE  xxxcolumn = 'xxx') 

    IF( @count = 0 ) --This means that the script has not been run yet      
      BEGIN 
          BEGIN TRANSACTION 

          --do work in here 
          COMMIT TRANSACTION 
      END 
    ELSE 
      BEGIN 
          SELECT 'This script has already been run before. Cannot run it again.' 
      END 
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH 
    IF( Xact_state() <> 0 ) 
      BEGIN 
          ROLLBACK TRAN 

          PRINT( 'ROLLED BACK TRANSACTION' ) 

          SELECT Error_number()  AS error_number, 
                 Error_line()    AS error_line, 
                 Error_message() AS error_message 
      END 
END CATCH
```

When the script fails, it enters the catch block and prints ROLLED BACK TRANSACTION and also displays the select statement results (error message etc).

But when I check in the database, the data until the point of failure is committed. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:** After rolling back the data, the latest identity value available changes. (Suppose the highest identity available is 10, if I insert and rollback, the highest identity available is 11 and not 10 anymore). So the roll back is does not return the database to the state before the transaction. This is what was causing the problems.

Comment: is it possible that in the stripped code, a commit is hiding? have you tried to monitor the execution of your statement to see when commits occur respectively changes are made to your database?

Comment: In the striped code there are no commits. There is only one commit at the end as shown in the above script :(

Comment: what error message are you getting when the script fails?

Comment: You have probaly stripped out the parts that would help us find the problem. If you are using an if exists stament to do an insert and the if exists is incorrect, it might be skipping that step rather than failing for instance. Or if you use dynamic SQL the problem could be with that. Without see the actual code, it is hard to tell what is happening

Comment: The database stores SSN and other sensitive data, publishing the actual code may compromise the security of the database :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your **update** re: IDENTITY value, this is expected behaviour. A rollback will not reset the IDENTITY value back, so it will generate gaps in your ID values.

Presumably that's what you mean when you say "the data until the point of failure is committed" - and **not** that all the data you've updated/inserted in the transaction is still there after the supposed rollback.